# Ruby on Rails self.joins or self.where doesn't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

my actual code looks like this

```
user_lesson = self.where("worked = ? AND passed = ?", true, false).order("lessons.sort")
```

But it doesn't work ... error is:

```
undefined method `where' for #<Membership:0x000000059f22e8>
```

.. I've tried it this way:

```
user_lesson = Membership.joins("user_lessons").where("id = ? AND worked = ? AND passed = ?",self.id, true, false).order("lessons.sort")
```

But then I got this error:

```
Unknown table 'memberships': SELECT `memberships`.*
FROM `memberships` user_lessons
WHERE (id = 4 AND worked = 1 AND passed = 0)
ORDER BY lessons.sort
```

How should it look like correctly?

Original Query

```
user_lesson = self.user_lessons.find :first,
  :include => [:lesson],
  :conditions => ["worked = ? AND passed = ?", true, false],
  :order => "lessons.sort"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the `where` method is defined at the class level rather than the instance level. In your second example (where you're doing `Membership.joins`) you are doing the right thing by calling `joins` and `where` on the `Membership` class rather than on an instance of that class. The reason you get an error with that second example is probably because you need to run your migrations to create the memberships table (if you have no migration you'll need to create one).

Comment: To slightly expand: a model instance is exactly one row in the database, this is what you get when you use `Membership.find(42)`, for example. Running `.where` on a *row* make no sense. This is why it needs to be on either on the model class (`Membership.where(...)`), or on a collection of rows (which is what `.where()` returns).

Comment: and how would look like a suitable solution?

Comment: If you need to simply call the where on a class while having its instance `self.class.where(..` will work, but you should try operating on scopes and relations instead

Comment: I've added the original query bevore I've done the transformation. `self.class.where` dosn't work